# Find which observable dependency change fired computed evaluation; dump the context

Tags: knockout.js

If I set a break point inside a knockout.js computed, I see two frames in the call stack (using Chrome's F12 facility)

- my computed (debugger stopped at the break point)
- knockout's `function evaluateImmediate()` at `var newValue = readFunction.call(evaluatorFunctionTarget);`

I believe knockout defers/throttles computed evaluation using a timeout mechanism. They must be storing the trigger(s) that caused the computed to re-evaluate, yes? Where?

Is there also a "remembered" context that is available to the evaluating computed? Where?

Comment: It would be easier to answer, if you would tell us why do you need this information, what are your goals with it and what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: thanks - I was looking for the concrete answer, which Brandon provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the `throttle` extender then yes the evaluation is deferred.  But the reason the evaluation was triggered is not stored.  It is unusual, when using Knockout, to care about which dependency triggered your evaluation.

Comment: I think it can often be useful when debugging to know why a particular evaluation was triggered.

Comment: In my case, I need to know why my app sends multiple ajax requests. The call is placed in side a `computed`. Remove the `throttle` does show the full call stack.